# How to disable certain rows selection using GWT Datagrid 2.4

Tags: gwt, datagrid, uibinder, gwt2

I am using GWT 2.4 version. How to disable row selection in GWT Datagrid.

In my Grid i have mixed records, But based on the condition i need to disable the row selection in DataGrid.

For Example : I have 2 rows with below values

EMP Name| EMP ID | Status

ABC     | 1001   | Active

ABC     | 1001   | In Active

When user click on 2nd row it should not be selected.

How to achieve this.
Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this with [default checkbox selection event manager](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/DefaultSelectionEventManager.html#createCheckboxManager()).

By default you would have a `CheckboxCell` that would handle row selection.
The trick is that you can override the `render()` method of the `CheckboxCell` and **do not render the checkbox if corresponding row is not allowed to be selected** by simply not calling `super.render()` method.

Below is a full working code for your example. You can not select rows that are not active. Please, notice the parameters of the constructor `new CheckboxCell(true, false)` - this is important.

```
public Widget test() {
    DataGrid<DatagridType> grid = new DataGrid<DatagridType>();

    final MultiSelectionModel<DatagridType> selectionModel = new MultiSelectionModel<DatagridType>(new ProvidesKey<DatagridType>() {
        @Override
        public Integer getKey(DatagridType item) {
            return item.getRowId();
        }
    });
    grid.setSelectionModel(selectionModel, DefaultSelectionEventManager.<DatagridType> createCheckboxManager());

    selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
            Window.alert(selectionModel.getSelectedSet().toString());
        }
    });

    grid.addColumn(new Column<DatagridType, Boolean>(new CheckboxCell(true, false)) {
        @Override
        public Boolean getValue(DatagridType object) {
            return selectionModel.isSelected(object);
        }

        @Override
        public void render(Context context, DatagridType object, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
            if(object.isActive())
                super.render(context, object, sb);
        }
    }, "Select");

    TextColumn<DatagridType> nameColumn = new TextColumn<DatagridType>() {
        @Override
        public String getValue(DatagridType object) {
            return object.getEmpName();
        }
    };

    TextColumn<DatagridType> idColumn = new TextColumn<DatagridType>() {
        @Override
        public String getValue(DatagridType object) {
            return Integer.toString(object.getEmpId());
        }
    };

    TextColumn<DatagridType> statusColumn = new TextColumn<DatagridType>() {
        @Override
        public String getValue(DatagridType object) {
            return object.isActive() ? "Active" : "In Acticve";
        }
    };

    grid.addColumn(nameColumn, "EMP Name");
    grid.addColumn(idColumn, "EMP ID");
    grid.addColumn(statusColumn, "Status");

    List<DatagridType> values = new ArrayList<DatagridType>();
    values.add(new DatagridType(0, "ABC", 1001, true));
    values.add(new DatagridType(1, "ABC", 1001, false));
    values.add(new DatagridType(2, "AAA", 1002, true));
    values.add(new DatagridType(3, "AAA", 1002, false));
    values.add(new DatagridType(4, "BBB", 1003, true));
    values.add(new DatagridType(5, "BBB", 1003, false));

    grid.setRowData(values);

    grid.setHeight("500px");

    Window.alert("Done");

    return grid;
}

private class DatagridType {
    private int rowId;
    private String empName;
    private int empId;
    private boolean active;

    public DatagridType(int rowId, String empName, int empId, boolean active) {
        this.rowId = rowId;
        this.empName = empName;
        this.empId = empId;
        this.active = active;
    }

    public int getRowId() {
        return rowId;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(rowId);
    }
}
```

I just had to add an unique row identifier as a selection id.

After each selection change you will see an alert with a list of selected row ids.

[image]